# 3D chart in silverlight4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

how to create 3D pie chart using silverlight 4 toolkit

Comment: Sometimes its better to buy code than to write it.  Your question is very broad; there is no reasonable way to answer it other than to hand you the coedz.  Also, creating custom controls like this is a complex and time consuming task.  Are you an experienced developer with lots of time?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Silverlight Toolkit does not support 3D pie charts.

From a data visualisation point of view, I would advise you to avoid using them at all! Pie charts are problematic for a variety of reasons. I would advise having a quick read of Stephen Few's essay ["Save the pies for dessert!"](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf) as to why pie charts, and more specifically 3d charts, are not recommended for most contexts.

Answer (score 1):

[Visiblox Charts](http://www.visiblox.com/) has [2D pie charts](http://www.visiblox.com/examples/PieChart). It is available as a free download so you won't need to buy the component, unless you want to remove the watermark. 3D charts, as Sam Hogarth says, are generally not the best way to display information.

Answer (score 0):

The Silverlight 4 Toolkit doesn't do 3D charts.  It will take more than just styling to create a 3D pie chart you would need to create a new data series type.

I hate giving these sorts of answers but the bottom line is, if really must have a 3D Chart buy a component that does it, there aren't any free ones (that I know of).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, The SL4 Toolkit doesn't have any 3D Charts. But Telerik does. They have a wide variety of 3D Charts that you can review at the links provided below:

**Bar Charts**

[3D Bar](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Bar) , [3D Stacked Bar](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedBar) ,  [3D Stacked Bar 100 Series](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedBar100)

**Line Charts**

[3DLine](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Line), [3D Stacked Line](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedLine)

**Area Charts**

[3D Area](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Area) , [3D Stacked Area](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedArea) , [3D Stacked Area 100 Series](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedArea100)

**Pie Charts**

[3D Doughnut](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Doughnut) , [3D Pie](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Pie)

Disclaimer: I work at Telerik as a XAML Evangelist.